# loopback handle long requests/processes

Tags: mysql, process, request, loopback

Suppose I receive a big csv file with lots of data in it, and the loopback server must parse all this data after the file is loaded, run some processes in it (Ex. Create user accounts and do some other registrations related to the account, or just create a database entry for each row in the file) and say this file has possibly from 10,000 to 3'000,000 entries (I'm using MySQL btw, maybe there is a better option for that too), it takes a lot of time to process all that, is there a "neat" way to handle that? right now what I'm doing is, after I get the file, I return the response to the user in my remote method `callback(null,{message:'got file, server still working'});` and continue to process in the background (in the same remote method code line, I just don't callback after done because I already did) and then I run a 500ms timer interval in the front-end to request the process status in a different endpoint (I save the progress percentage in a field's row on the database, for this endpoint to request), is this the way to do this? or is there a better option? I already run mysql queries in groups of 10,000 each commit and I disable foreign key checking too (I'm using mysql connector query execution directly). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Off-Topic: What is your issue? why you want to change the current method? Always be specific and make your best effort before asking, and don't treat Stack Overflow as a repository of tutorials. You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you as "an advice". Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, I was asking what is the "best practice" in this case.

Comment: Well I have to tell you that this is an "special case" so "best practices" does not apply here. A best practice is method or technique that has been generally accepted as *superior* to any alternatives because it produces results that are much better to those achieved by other means or because it has become a *standard way* of doing things.

Comment: Oh :o, ok, I thought this was something commonly faced by other loopback developers, thanks anyway, and sorry for asking, didn't mean to spam stack overflow :)

Comment: Man I'm trying to help you. You can improve this question. Just  show part of your code that you don't like and be very specific why is not good for you and what do you think is a good solution then you will see nice comments trying to help you.